# C# Cannot Implicity Convert type 'Char[]' to 'Char?'

Tags: c#, char, implicit

I searched and searched, but couldn't find anything remotely similar.
According to everything I've come to know, it should work.

```
  string strTest, strSubTest, strDesc;
        using (GenericParser parser = new GenericParser())
        {
            parser.SetDataSource(@"D:\work.csv");

            parser.ColumnDelimiter = @",".ToCharArray();
            parser.FirstRowHasHeader = true;
            parser.MaxBufferSize = 4096;
            parser.MaxRows = 200;

            while (parser.Read())
            {
                strTest = parser["Test"];
                strSubTest = parser["Subtest"];
                strDesc = parser["Description"];
                Console.WriteLine(strTest);
```

The code that states @",".ToCharArray(); states the error in the title. I've never seen an implicit conversion like that before 'Char?'. Any idea what I did wrong?

If you need some background, I used the GenericParser found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11698/A-Portable-and-Efficient-Generic-Parser-for-Flat-F

Comment: Is what it says. Can't convert an *array* of characters to a single char. Try: `parser.ColumnDelimiter = ','` instead (look at the documentation/intellisense for the applicable type).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(note the single quotes)

```
parser.ColumnDelimiter = ',';
```

Comment: I love you. I guess I didn't exactly why the tutorial wanted to use ".ToCharArray". In the tutorial it had the code exactly as I did. Anyways, Thanks a ton mate!

Comment: Be sure to hit the checkmark if this answer did it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

the question mark is a modifier to value types like char, int, and double to make them nullable. So where `char x = null;` is a syntax error, `char? x = null;` works. `char?` actually a shorthand syntax for `Nullable<char>`. `Nullable<T>` can't be used with reference types, as they are already nullable. `Nullable<T>` objects have two properties, `bool HasValue`, which should be obvious, and `T Value`, which returns the encapsulated value if HasValue is true, or throws an exception if it is false.

So, you can't set `Delimeter` to a character array, because it is expecting either a character or null.